# Using PowerShell to move files and leave text file

Tags: powershell

If I am using PowerShell to search for folders in a drive to move them to another folder from a CSV. I'm drawing a blank on how to leave a text file for the folder that is moved in a replacement folder.

Current PowerShell code to locate folder & move:

```
$File = Import-Csv C:\share\test\files.txt
foreach ($fileName in $File.FileName) {
    Move-Item -Path "C:\share\test\OldLocation\$fileName" -Destination "C:\share\test\NewLocation\$fileName"
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me where exactly you want to place those text files.

Comment: Are you trying to move the **files** from the old location and instead leave a text file saying so in that same old location or are you trying to move an entire **folder**? The title says 'move files', but in the question you are talking about 'search for folders in a drive to move them'. Be specific please

Comment: I am moving folders in a network drive and I want to leave a text file in a folder named the same thing but just has a text file in it that says "Contact IT this folder has been archived".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I go by the title of this question and suppose you want to move **files** to a new location,
**AND** your CSV looks anything like this:

```
FileName
file1.docx
file2.docx
file3.docx
image1.jpg
```

This should do it:

```
$oldLocation = 'C:\share\test\OldLocation'
$newLocation = 'C:\share\test\NewLocation'
# this is the path and filename for the text to leave behind
$movedFiles  = Join-Path -Path $oldLocation -ChildPath 'Files Moved.txt'

$messages    = @()
$filesToMove = Import-Csv 'C:\share\test\files.txt'
foreach ($file in $filesToMove.FileName) {
    $oldFile = Join-Path -Path $oldLocation -ChildPath $file
    $newFile = Join-Path -Path $newLocation -ChildPath $file

    if (Test-Path -Path $oldFile -PathType Leaf) {
        ################################################################################################
        # WARNING: Using parameter '-Force' will overwrite any file in the new location with that name. 
        # If that is not what you want, what will be your strategy ?
        ################################################################################################

        Move-Item -Path $oldFile -Destination $newFile    # -Force
        # add a new line for the text file
        $messages += "File '$file' has been moved to '$newLocation'"
    }
}
if ($messages.Count) {
    # write the textfile with all the files that have been moved in the old location
    Add-Content -Path $movedFiles -Value ($messages -join [Environment]::NewLine)
}
else {
    Write-Warning "No files have been moved."
}
```

After the files have been moved, the old location should have a textfile containing

```
File 'file1.docx' has been moved to 'C:\share\test\NewLocation'
File 'file2.docx' has been moved to 'C:\share\test\NewLocation'
File 'file3.docx' has been moved to 'C:\share\test\NewLocation'
File 'image1.jpg' has been moved to 'C:\share\test\NewLocation'
```

Comment: This is basically what I'm looking to do except I'm not giving the new location just letting them know to contact me